# var_dump() without show protected and private property

Tags: php

Is there any functions or how to var_dump() object without showing it protected and private property?

example:

```
class foo {
    public $public = 'public';
    protected $protected = 'protected';
    private $private = 'private';
}

$Foo = new foo;
var_dump($Foo);
// Expected output "(string) public"
```

Comment: why? var_dump is for debugging. it's SUPPOSED to show you everything in there. It's not meant to be a output formatter for general usage.

Comment: @MarcB Because on my object, class contain active record (private property). I don't need that to show, because it's a long list. I want when i debug it, i just want to see short list, which it's is the public properties.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [this](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/6/7/6) page shows, you can just loop over the object:

```
<?php
    class person {
        public $FirstName = "Bill";
        public $MiddleName = "Terence";
        public $LastName = "Murphy";
        private $Password = "Poppy";
        public $Age = 29;
        public $HomeTown = "Edinburgh";
        public $FavouriteColour = "Purple";
    }

    $bill = new person();

    foreach($bill as $var => $value) {
        echo "$var is $value\n";
    }
?>
```

> Note that the $Password variable is nowhere in sight, because it is marked Private and we're trying to access it from the global scope.

If you want to make your own var dump, you can do it as so:

```
function dumpObj( $obj )
{
    foreach( $obj as $k=>$v )
    {
        echo $k . ' : ' . $v ."\n";
    }
}

dumpObj( new WhateverClass() );
```

The reason this works is because when you access the object outside of itself, you only have access to its public facing member variables.

Comment: Great! this can be another solutions.

Comment: It will be nice if your function also output the variable type.

Answer (score 7):

`json_encode` will only encode public properties.

Answer (score 0):

How's about `json_decode(json_encode($obj))`?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to use the __clone method in your class. There you can unset any undesired properties from the clone of your object instance, e.g.:

```
public function __clone() {
    unset( $this->my_secret_property ); 
}
```

then your var_dump would reference the clone:

```
var_dump( clone My_Object_Instance );
```

Or, if you need your cloning elsewhere, your class can use the __debugInfo() method to completely control its var_dump output, such as returning get_object_vars( $this ), after you unset any unwanted array elements.