# var_dump(): Property access is not allowed yet

Tags: php, mysqli

I have a simple object mapping implementation

```
class Database
{
    protected string $Host = '';
    protected string $Port = '';
    protected string $Database = '';
    protected string $User = '';
    protected string $Password = '';
    protected object $Instance;
    protected string $sql = '';

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Host     = getenv("DB_HOST");
        $this->User     = getenv("DB_USERNAME");
        $this->Password = getenv("DB_PASSWORD");
        $this->Database = getenv("DB_DATABASE");
        $this->Port     = getenv("DB_PORT");
    }

    public function connect()
    {
        $con = mysqli_connect($this->Host, $this->User, $this->Password, $this->Database, $this->Port);

        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            die($this->getError());
        } else {
            $this->Instance = $con;
        }

        return $this->Instance;
    }

    public function unconnect()
    {
        if ($this->Instance->close() === false) {
            die($this->getError());
        }
    }

    public function getPrimaryKey(string $table)
    {
        $this->connect();
        $this->sql = "SHOW COLUMNS FROM " . $table . ";";
        $results   = $this->Instance->query($this->sql);
        foreach ($results as $row) {
            if ($row["Key"] == "PRI") {
                $this->unconnect();
                return $row["Field"];
            }
        }
    }
}

class ObjectMapping
{
    protected string $ClassName = '';
    protected object $Database;
    protected object $Object;
    protected string $PrimaryKey = '';
    protected array  $ForeignKeys = [];

    public function __construct($object)
    {
        $this->Object = $object;

        $this->Database    = new Database();
        $classPathArray    = explode("\\", get_class($object));
        $this->ClassName   = $classPathArray[count($classPathArray) - 1];
        $this->PrimaryKey  = $this->Database->getPrimaryKey(strtolower($this->ClassName));
    }


    public function find(string $id)
    {
        var_dump($this->Object);
        exit;
    }
}

class Model
{
    protected $Mapper;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->Mapper = new ObjectMapping($this);
    }

    public function find($id)
    {
        $mappedObject = $this->Mapper->find($id);

        return $mappedObject;
    }
}

class Coupons extends Model
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function __destruct() {}
}

$coupon = new Coupons();

$coupon = $coupon->find(11);
```

Given code above I got error during dumping variable `var_dump($this->Object);`

This error

> var_dump(): Property access is not allowed yet

Upon tracing, I will only got this when calling `$this->unconnect();` on Database class.

See method `getPrimaryKey()`.

Anyone has solution?

Comment: Take a look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12307790/var-dump-without-show-protected-and-private-property.

Comment: BTW This is not a php 7.4 related issue. Only typed properties are related here, which are not what causing this issue.

Comment: This is not fair: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59360620/warning-var-dump-property-access-is-not-allowed-yet

Comment: Aside from that this error will show if some object reference does not exist ex `someFunc(&obj) { return $obj; }` then `someFunc($users);` if `$users` is not an object the error show. I think this is php way of checking if the object is completely built and it properties and methods are callable.

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to work with a `mysqli` object, which has already been closed with the `close()` method. The source code for the mysqli extension has some checks if the `status` of the mysqli object is high enough to access the property values. As from the [`/ext/mysqli/mysqli_prop.c` file](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/5d6e923d46a89fe9cd8fb6c3a6da675aa67197b4/ext/mysqli/mysqli_prop.c#L30-L35):

> ```
> #define CHECK_STATUS(value) \
> if (!obj->ptr || ((MYSQLI_RESOURCE *)obj->ptr)->status < value ) { \
>     php_error_docref(NULL, E_WARNING, "Property access is not allowed yet"); \
>     ZVAL_FALSE(retval); \
>     return retval; \
> } \
> ```

When the status isn't high enough (like `MYSQLI_STATUS_VALID`, depending on the property) you will get this warning.

To solve your problem do not try to work with the `mysqli` object when it has been closed. You can simply set `$this->Instance` to `null` after you have closed the connection.

Answer (score 1):

***Edit***

As of PHP 7.4.3 this is a [fixed bug](https://github.com/kocsismate/php-src/commit/d39edebbce35890aafd77cc47e1830e851287219)

---

In addition to what **@Progman** said. this is a quote from the [PHP Documentation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php)

> non-persistent MySQL connections and result sets are automatically
>   destroyed when a PHP script finishes

So you don't actually need to close the connection but if you do, you can close it inside the `__destruct` method.

```
public function __destruct() {
    $this->Instance->close();
}
```

**Note:** If `xdebug` is enabled it will limit the var_dump() output for `$this->Object` to 3 levels deep.

To change the default you can set `xdebug.var_display_max_depth` in the `xdebug.ini` file:

```
xdebug.var_display_max_depth = -1
```

> -1 means 1023 which is the maximum value.